# Replacing kernel for a Poisson distribution in an equation

Tags: density-function

In Example 4.4.2 on page 163 of [Statistical Inference](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0534243126), the following is implied:

$\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\frac{((1 - p)\lambda)^t}{t!} = e^{(1-p)\lambda}$

with a note that says "[the] sum is a kernel for a Poisson distribution". I understand the Poisson distribution, but I don't fully grasp the kernel concept yet. I tried searching for this identity, but couldn't find it. Can someone help me understand this, or provide  references that I can use for background information?

Update: I initially had the incorrect equation above. I corrected it after Anand's comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I checked the book and there is a typo in your question. It should be

\begin{align*} 
\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \frac{((1-p) \lambda)^t}{t!} & = e^{(1-p) \lambda}
\end{align*}

The above formula basically follows from the definition of an [exponential function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function)
\begin{align*} 
\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^t}{t!} & = e^{x}
\end{align*}

and once you substitute $x = (1-p) \lambda$ you get your desired result.

The above result can be derived using the Poisson probability mass function (`pmf`) which the authors refer to  "[the] sum is a kernel for a Poisson distribution". This follows from the fact the `pmf` should sum to $1$.

\begin{align*} 
\sum_{x} \Pr(X = x) &= 1
\end{align*}

The `pmf` of Poisson is given by 
\begin{align*} 
\Pr(X = x) &= \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{x}}{x!}
\end{align*}

Using the above two equations, we get 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{x} \Pr(X = x) &= \sum_{x} \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{x}}{x!} = 1
\end{align*}

Multiply both sides by $e^{\lambda}$ we get 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{x} \frac{\lambda^{x}}{x!} = e^{\lambda}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the corrections! I updated my question with the proper equation.